# Change Ionic icon on hover

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Is it possible to change the icon on hover without going through the component?

```
  <button ion-button icon-only #lock (mouseover)="lock.isHover = true" (mouseout)="lock.isHover = false">
    <ion-icon *ngIf="lock.isHover" name="lock"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon *ngIf="!lock.isHover" name="unlock"></ion-icon>
  </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly your question given the code example.
You could use ternary to change the name value based on lock.isHover's value.

```
  <button ion-button icon-only #lock (mouseover)="lock.isHover = true" (mouseout)="lock.isHover = false">
    <ion-icon [name]="lock.isHover ? 'lock' : 'unlock'"></ion-icon>
  </button>
```

If you try to change only for visual purpose I would go with css path:

```
  button:hover ion-icon{
   // css styling for hover state
  }
```

Comment: it's not working as expected: `Property 'isHover' does not exist on type 'IonButton'.` (with Ionic 6.6 and Angular 15)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using (mouseenter) and (mouseleave) instead. This way, the event is clear. 'mouseover' could cause the icon to rapidly toggle back and forth.